# How can I send custom header of cross origin request in AngularJS + Web Api 2?

Tags: c#, angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 project:

```
[AuthorizeUser]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/value/get")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

And configuration in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And request from client AngularJS:

```
$scope.getvalue = function () {
            var url = "http://localhost:59073/api/value/get";
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                header: {
                    'x-access-token': 'abc'
                }
            }).then(function onSuccess(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }).then(function onError(err) {
                console.log(res);
            });
        }
```

But I can not get my custom header "x-access-token" of POST Request Header in server side. And I also don't see any OPTIONS request in Network tab of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late. It will help someone who encounters the same issue. In your example, you have assigned an object for the header property. I think this is a typo. It should be headers instead of the header.

```
var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://example.com',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type':'x-access-token': 'abc'
   },
   data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Please refer to the official docs of Angular1.x

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers